# Hyperlink formula for sending email in outlook

Tags: excel, email, excel-formula, hyperlink

I am trying to automate a task that's repetitive but I'm aware that hyperlink doens't allow me to copy and paste a range of cells so I'm doing the tedious task of trying to format it correctly but it seems the amount of blank cells in a string is creating too much of a issue. Is there a way to edit it to where I don't have to have so much white space to create the format I need?

I should mention, when I evaluate the formula, it returns everything correctly but then it gets to "Send Email" and I get a #VALUE error.

The goal is to format it into 4 columns and space it out.

(The only reason why I'm using a formula instead of VBA is because the higher-ups do not want VBA due to how sensitive the spreadsheet is.)

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:" & F16 & "?subject=Testing" &"&body=" & "    Product    " & "     Agvance Blend Ticket     " & "     Invoice/ Transfers #     " & "     Qty     " & "%0A"
& CONCATENATE("     ", C5,"                ",E5,"                ",F5, "                ", G5) & "%0A"
& CONCATENATE("     ", C6,"                ",E6,"                ",F6, "                ", G6),"Send Email")
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Could you be more specific?

Comment: I've put in the formula, using HYPERLINK to try to do that. It seems the spaces in the strings are causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

If whitespace is the problem, then don't use it; use the Outlook tab character instead, e.g.

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:" &F16&"?subject=Testing&body=%09Product%09%09Agvance Blend Ticket%09%09Invoice/ Transfers #%09%09Qty%0A"
&CONCATENATE("%09",C5,"%09%09",E5,"%09%09%09%09",F5,"%09%09%09%09",G5,"%0A")
&CONCATENATE("%09",C6,"%09%09",E6,"%09%09%09%09",F6,"%09%09%09%09",G6),"Send Email")
```

sample draft email
[image: Screenshot of email produced by formula proposed]

Comment: So that's a huge help, is there a limit to how many times I can use that as I tried to add a third line of &CONCATENATE(...) but next row but kept getting a value error?

Comment: Turns out there's indeed a limit, a 255 character limit. 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-i-increase-the-number-of-characters-when/c5e6db2b-64bf-4e3a-a53b-ff952f6e7bdd

Comment: If you come up against this issue (bureaucrats insisting on VBA-free files) a lot then you should explore [Application Events/Class modules](https://youtu.be/SaQfOIeOuHk) so that you can have VBA code run on VBA-free files (although it does require all users to have some code in common in their personal macro workbooks)